# Adobe Scout empty project using Air 14 on Android and iOS, something's broken

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, mobile

I need some input here, check out the screen shots below. This is a totally empty FlashDevelop project.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/414973/as_ss.jpg

The Main class extends sprite and it's constructor is totally empty. The project is set to 60 fps and I compile for Android and Scout gives me all kinds of crazy jumps and spikes, some over the red 60 fps line while iOS does as expected.

What gives? I'm trying to trouble shoot performance on a game and I wanted to see what an empty project looked like to establish a base line and no wonder the Android version has issues. Is there a bug in Adobe Air 14?

Thanks for any info! -Josh

Comment: I just replicated on a Samsung S3 and an old Scroll Excell 7 inch tablet albeit using Flash Pro to deploy. I extended sprite in my document class with empty constructor. I didn't quite get the ios level chart you did (I can't test on any IOS devices)but was a lot closer and nowhere near as bad as your Android. What devices did you test on? (I used AIR 14 and 15 both same results). Do you have many apps running in the background on the android device? Do you have power saving turned on? Having power saving on really affected one of my games on some but not all devices I tested on.

Comment: If this is a debug build, try exporting a release build instead. Debug builds are highly inconsistent with AIR.

Comment: Notice that there are networking events in the android screenshot. Perhaps android's AIR runtime (iOS is not the runtime) is doing something behind the scenes with some of Adobe's new marketing / cross-game-promotion crap.  That'd be disappointing!

Comment: Hey, sorry for not responding to this. Josh Janusch hit the nail on the head. It was debug and not release. Although still release on Android was still a bit jumpy on an empty build.

InkeyString I was testing on an iPhone 4s, iPad 3 and a Note 3. The game I was working on back in October that I asked this question about, is done and on the app stores, if you're curious.

Android:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.bigdickensgames.attraction

Apple:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/attraction-for-ios/id937067656?ls=1&mt=8

Thanks for the responses! - Josh